# Master-Detail show data SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server and I have this 3 tables

**STUDENTS**

```
| id | student |
-------------
| 1  | Ronald  |
| 2  | Jenny   |
```

**SCORES**

```
| id | score | period | student |
| 1  |   8   |   1    |    1    |
| 2  |   9   |   2    |    1    |
```

**PERIODS**

```
| id | period |
| 1  |   1    |
| 2  |   2    |
| 3  |   3    |
| 4  |   4    |
```

And I want a query that returns this result:

```
| student | score1 | score2 | score3 | score4 |
| Ronald  |   8    |   9    |  null  |  null  |
| Jenny   |  null  |  null  |  null  |  null  |
```

As you can see, the number of scores depends of the periods because sometimes it can be 4 o 3 periods.

I don't know if I have the wrong idea or should I make this in the application, but I want some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `PIVOT` your data e.g.

```
select Y.Student, [1], [2], [3], [4]
from (
  select T.Student, P.[Period], S.Score
  from Students T
  cross join [Periods] P
  left join Scores S on S.[Period] = P.id and S.Student = T.id
) X
pivot
(
  sum(Score)
  for [Period] in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) Y
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-20